Gauge boson interacting with derivative of the Higgs field
Consider the $\mathrm{SU}(2)\times \mathrm U(1)_Y$ Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal L=-\frac{1}{4} (W^a_{\mu\nu})^2
-\frac{1}{4} B_{\mu\nu}^2 + 
(D_\mu H)^\dagger (D^\mu H) 
+m^2 H^\dagger H 
-\lambda (H^\dagger H)^2.
$$
The covariant derivative is
$$
D_\mu H=\partial_\mu H - igW_\mu^a t^a H - \frac{1}{2} ig'B_\mu H.
$$
If we expand
$$
H=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ v+h
\end{bmatrix}
$$
we'll get the mass terms for the bosons and the interaction terms.
However, the term in (29.4) in which the covariant higgs excitation component $\partial _\mu h$ couples to the gauge bosons is neglected in the literature. Is there a reason for this?
Reference: Schwartz Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model P 584-P587.

They are not neglected, you just need to choose an appropriate Gauge fixing function in the Faddeev-Popov method. See Peskin & Schroeder, section 21.1.

The pages you are referring to are on Spontaneous Symmetry Breaking, and the Higgs particle, h, is "debris" in the process and the Higgs mechanism, mere dross, so your text wisely postpones interaction terms with h in them, in its own words! (Read on to the next section, 29.2, specifically (29.14).)
The point is this particle/excitation,h, in contrast to the three goldstone π, cannot be "eaten" by a gauge boson, and its peculiar group theory protects it from any crucially significant role in the Higgs mechanism. Specifically, the terms in (29.4) containing $\partial_\mu h$ are just the kinetic term $\partial_\mu h \partial^\mu h/2$, and the linear terms vanish by the antihermiticity of the covariant completion! The h is neutral w.r.t. the groups.
So you have learned and appreciated, presumably, that h itself does not significantly affect the SSB picture; it's not even charged under EM, so a single derivative cannot go into its pointless EM current (non)coupling; and you might even, naively, assume, for the sake of argument, it is infinitely massive so you could completely ignore its effects, to organize your thinking. (Not really, but that's second order "fine print"...)
Full analyses of the SM do compute the effects on quantities of the finite Higgs mass, 125.11±0.11GeV. Higgs physics is one of the most vigorous focus areas of LHC research at present, cf PDG. Dependence of custodial symmetry breaking  on the mass of the Higgs reveals its role in such fine print: cf the paragraph following (11.9) there.
In section 29.3.2, your text, later, argues & requires, and experiments have confirmed (!), the fundamental proportionality of the coupling of the Higgs-to-fermions to the masses of these fermions!

Look at a simpler model, with a charged scalar and a $U(1)$ field $A_\mu$. Then we have
$$
\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} + \left(D_\mu \Phi\right)^\dagger \left(D^\mu \Phi\right)
$$
With $D_\mu \Phi = \partial_\mu \Phi - i e A_\mu \Phi$, where $e$ is the charge of $\Phi$, and focusing on the interaction terms between $A$ and $\partial \Phi$, we have
$$
\mathcal{L} \supset -i e A_\mu \left(\Phi^\dagger \partial^\mu \Phi - \Phi \partial^\mu \Phi^\dagger\right)
$$
where $\supset$ means "the left hand side includes the term on the right hand side".
To be very explicit, let's write $\Phi=h + i \phi$ (the weird notation here will make sense in a minute). Then this term becomes
$$
\mathcal{L} \supset -2 i e A_\mu \left(h \partial^\mu \phi - \phi\partial^\mu h\right)
$$
Note that if $\Phi$ were real (so $\phi=0$), then the term in brackets would be zero. Of course, $\Phi$ being complex is what allows it to have electric charge, so $e=0$ as well, but let's ignore that for now.
Now come back to your example. You have not written the most general perturbation for $H$. The most general perturbation would be
$$
H = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
\phi_1 + i \phi_2 \\
v + h + i \phi_3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where $v$ is the VEV, and $\phi_{1,2,3}$ and $h$ are real fields.
If we carried through the Lagrangian with all of these terms, we would indeed find interactions like
$$
\mathcal{L} \supset \# g' B_\mu \left(h \partial^\mu \phi_3 - \phi_3 \partial^\mu h \right)
$$
where $\#$ is some numerical factor that I'm not going to work out.
However, you have chosen a gauge where $\phi_1=\phi_2=\phi_3=0$ (this is often called "unitary gauge"). In this gauge, these interactions do not appear (in the tree level Lagrangian), basically because $h$ by itself is not charged.
Because of the Goldstone-boson equivalence principle, if you were to work in a gauge where $\phi_{1,2,3}$ were not zero (which generically happens in a Lorentz covariant gauge), you can think of the interactions with the scalar fields as describing interactions among the longitudinal modes of the massive vector fields. In unitary gauge, you've effectively moved those interactions from the scalar fields (or a combination of the scalars and vector fields) into the vector fields directly.
Also was pointed out in the comments, if you include a gauge-fixing term and Fadeev-Popov ghosts, you will find remnants of this interaction appear that you need to account for at loop level.
